# Does List<>.OrderBy() check if the list is sorted?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

In a game I am developing I need to sort a list of objects in order to determine in which order they are to be rendered. I need to to sort the list each frame, which is 60 times per second. However it is likely the list will already be in order, except on the first frame of the game after start.

So my question is whether the OrderBy method of List<> checks if the list is already ordered before using whatever algorithm it uses to sort? Since most of the time my list will be sorted it would be quite a waste of time to resort it anyway.

Comment: Could you use a stack? If you know you want the last element added, you could use a stack to get the last added element returned first. That way you can still use your List<> as well

Answer (score 2):

It's not `List<T>.OrderBy`, it's `Enumerable.OrderBy` and no it doesn't check if the list is already sorted. You can see the source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs,dfa04762cc2dcf3e), if you wanna keep your list sorted all the time I suggest you to use [`SortedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I don't know if the sorted list would fit. The reason I need to sort it all the time is that the elements themselves change, and therefore might be in a different spot in the list from frame to frame (the list is sorted by the Y value of the object in the game world, which changes if the object moves). Maybe I should just implement my own way of checking if I need to sort?